# Uninstalling an application via uninstallString using powershell in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, wmi

I am trying to uninstall software using below Powershell script in an WPF application

```
get-package |where name -like "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)" |% { & $_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] /S}
```

the above command works only for **Notepad++ (64-bit x64)** but fails when I tried with software's like **Git version 2.25.1** and **TortoiseGit 2.10.0.0 (64 bit)**

For **Git version 2.25.1**

```
get-package |where name -like "Git version 2.25.1" |% { & $_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] /S}
```

I am getting the below error:

> & : The term '"C:\Program Files\Git\unins001.exe"' is not recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:59
>   + ... "Git version 2.25.1" |% { & $_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] /S}
>   +                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:\Program Files\Git\unins001.exe":String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

For TortoiseGit 2.10.0.0 (64 bit)

```
 get-package |where name -like "TortoiseGit 2.10.0.0 (64 bit)" |% { & $_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] /S}
```

I am getting below error:

> The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that
>   was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a
>   CommandInfo object. At line:1 char:70
>   + ... t 2.10.0.0 (64 bit)" |% { & $_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] /S}
>   +                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression

I also tried using WMI objects powershell script below is the script

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where {$_.Name -like \"{returnStr}\"}  | foreach {$_.Uninstall()}".Replace("{returnStr}", Notepad++ (64-bit x64))
```

Above script only works for the software's that were installed via an MSI

If anyone has suggestions on how to proceed it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can find Uninstall-Package your friend here:

```
get-package | where-object name -like "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)" | ForEach {uninstall-package}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried with the mentioned script but I am getting error -Uninstall-Package : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:75
+ ... ect name -like "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)" | ForEach {uninstall-package}
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Uninstall-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage

Comment: Hi ,I tried with the command: `get-package | where-object name -like "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)" | ForEach {Uninstall-Package -Name $_.Name }` , I did not get any error however package is still not getting uninstalled.

Comment: Try removing the ForEach and just Uninstall-Package after pipeline.

Comment: Hi, tried with the command : `get-package | where-object name -like "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)"| Uninstall-Package` ,same issue no error and still package remains uninstalled.

Also,I noticed the same command is working for **TortoiseGit 2.10.0.0 (64 bit)**

Comment: That only works with msi providers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get rid of the double quotes.  Replacing `"` with $null or no 2nd arg.
Uninstall-package doesn't work for non msi installs.  Also this only works in windows powershell 5.1, not powershell 7 currently.  Does TortoiseGit have an uninstallstring?

```
get-package "*Git version 2.25.1*" | 
  % { & ($_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] -replace '"') /S}
```